Page not found 404 for about
This error is coming .Can someone please help me to come out from that
GPage not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/about
Using the URLconf defined in Hello.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
[name='home']
The current path, about, didn’t match any of these.
You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
code related to that are:
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("This is Home Page")

def about(request):
    return HttpResponse("This is About Page")

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from home import views
urlpatterns = [
    path("",views.index,name='home'),
    path("about/",views.about,name='about'),
]


from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('home.urls'))
]

normal page is working as This is home page.Admin page was also working but now it is also not working.

Based on the information you've provided, it seems that the issue is with your URL configuration
In your home/urls.py file, you have defined the 'about' URL pattern as:
path("about/",views.about,name='about'),

This means that the 'about' URL should be accessed at the root level, i.e., 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/about/' (note the trailing slash).
To fix this issue, try the following:
Make sure you're accessing the correct URL: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/about/' (with a trailing slash).
If you prefer to access the 'about' page without a trailing slash, you can modify the URL pattern in home/urls.py like this:
path("about", views.about, name='about'),  # Remove the trailing slash

Restart your Django development server after making these changes.
As for the admin page not working, make sure your INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py includes 'django.contrib.admin' and that you've run migrations (python manage.py migrate)
